# Efficient Array Normalization

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, arrays

I want to normalize elements in an array. The solution I found is to take the sum of the elements and divide each element with this total. Can you find more efficient way of doing this?

The runtime I achieve is 2N. Any better idea?

```
normalize(array)
{
   sum = 0;

   for i = 0 to array.size() do
      sum += array[i];
   end

   for i = 0 to array.size() do
      array[i] /= sum;
   end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that at least N "operations" are needed since each array element is affected, you can't get the number of operations down by much. It's not clear what your complexity measure exactly is – why is `sum += array[i]` a single operation? What about the loop? The actual CPU needs to increment `i` and compare it to `array.size()`, there are jumps involved and so on. The operation `sum += array[i]` is probably more than one instruction. Not to mention things you actually forgot to count, like `sum = 0`.

That said, I can't see how to improve on your algorithm, and I don't think it's possible, though as mentioned above, the notion of complexity is very shaky here, so perhaps there is a "trick" which will work under your complexity measure, whatever it is.